# How can i set thirdlevel property in C#

Tags: c#, properties

```
string sObjectValue="Caption";
PropertyInfo mainProperty= grdData.GetType().GetProperty("MasterTableView");
PropertyInfo subProperty1= mainProperty.PropertyType.GetProperty("EditFormSettings");
PropertyInfo subProperty2= subProperty1.PropertyType.GetProperty("InsertCaption");

subProperty2.SetValue(subProperty1, sObjectValue); //ERROR : Object does not match target type.
```

Here `grdData` is a RadGrid,
I want to set thirdlevel property like:

```
grdData.MasterTableView.EditFormSettings.InsertCaption = "Caption";
```

How I can make my code work?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
PropertyInfo MasterTableView  => grdData.GetType().GetProperty("MasterTableView);
PropertyInfo EditFormSettings => MasterTableView.PropertyType.GetProperty("EditFormSettings");
PropertyInfo InsertCaption 
{
    get { return EditFormSettings.Property.GetProperty("InsertCaption");
    set { EditFormSettings.Property.GetProperty("InsertCaption") = value}
}
```